# Stanford NLP - Using Parsed or Tagged text to generate Full XML

Tags: parsing, nlp, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger

I'm trying to extract data from the PennTreeBank, Wall Street Journal corpus. Most of it already has the parse trees, but some of the data is only tagged.
i.e. wsj_DDXX.mrg and wsj_DDXX.pos files.

I would like to use the already parsed trees and tagged data in these files so as not to use the parser and taggers within CoreNLP, but I still want the output file format that CoreNLP gives; namely, the XML file that contains the dependencies, entity coreference, and the parse tree and tagged data.

I've read many of the java docs but I cannot figure out how to get it the way I described.

For POS, I tried using the [LexicalizedParser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp-3.5.2/edu/stanford/nlp/parser/lexparser/LexicalizedParser.html) and it allows me to use the tags, but I can only generate an XML file with the some of the information I want; there is no option for coreference or generating the parse trees. To get it to correctly generate the sub-optimal XML files here, I had to write a script to get rid of all of the brackets within the files. This is the command I use:

> java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser -outputFormat typedDependenciesCollapsed,wordsAndTags -outputFilesExtension xml -outputFormatOptions xml -writeOutputFiles -outputFilesDirectory my\dir -tokenized -tagSeparator / -tokenizerFactory edu.stanford.nlp.process.WhitespaceTokenizer -tokenizerMethod newCoreLabelTokenizerFactory edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz my\wsj\files\dir

I also can't generate the data I would like to have for the WSJ data that already has the trees. I tried using what is said [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#s) and I looked at the corresponding Javadocs. I used the command similar to what is described. But I had to write a python program to retrieve the stdout data resulting from analyzing each file and wrote it into a new file. This resulting data is only a text file with the dependencies and is not in the desired XML notation.

To summarize, I would like to use the POS and tree data from these PTB files in order to generate a CoreNLP parse corresponding to what would occur if I used CoreNLP on a regular text file. The pseudo command would be like this:

> java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.CoreNLP -useTreeFile wsj_DDXX.mrg

and

> java -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.CoreNLP -usePOSFile wsj_DDXX.pos

Edit: fixed a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, but a bit tricky and there is no out of the box feature that can do this, so you will have to write some code. The basic idea is to replace the `tokenize`, `ssplit` and `pos` annotators (and in case you also have trees the `parse` annotator) with your code that loads these annotations from your annotated files.

On a very high level you have to do the following:

- Load your trees with `MemoryTreebank`
- Loop through all the trees and for each tree create a sentence `CoreMap` to which you add

  - a `TokensAnnotation`
  - a `TreeAnnotation` and the `SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations`
- Create an `Annotation` object with a list containing the `CoreMap` objects for all sentences
- Run the StanfordCoreNLP pipeline with the `annotators` option set to `lemma,ner,dcoref` and the option `enforceRequirements` set to `false`.

Take a look at the individual annotators to see how to add the required annotations. E.g. there is a method in [ParserAnnotatorUtils](https://github.com/stanfordnlp/CoreNLP/blob/master/src/edu/stanford/nlp/pipeline/ParserAnnotatorUtils.java#L29) that adds the `SemanticGraphCoreAnnotations`.